# Ошибка fs.readdir(): "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory" при запуске приложения из другой папки

Tags: node.js

Когда запускаю программу на сервере из её папки (node index.js), все работает исправно.

Но, если запустить из другой директории (node /opt/webserver/index.js), выдает ошибку:

> { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './routers',
> errno: -2,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'scandir',
> path: './routers' }

```
fs.readdir('./routers', (error, files) => {
    if(error) return console.log(error);
    files.forEach(file => {
        app.use(require(`./routers/${file}`));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы понять что происходит, надо написать маленький скрипт и позапускать из разных мест:

```
const path = require('path');

console.log(`cwd=${process.cwd()}, dirname=${__dirname}`);
console.log(`path1=${path.resolve('./routes')}, path2=${path.resolve(__dirname, './routes')}`);
```

Результат:

```
:~ $ node tmp/q/src/dirname.js 
cwd=/Users/z, dirname=/Users/z/tmp/q/src
path1=/Users/z/routes, path2=/Users/z/tmp/q/src/routes
```

Видно, что `./routes` "резолвятся" от места запуска программы.

Нужно добавить использование глобальной переменной `__dirname`, чтобы "резолвить" от местоположения запущенного файла.

Например, так:

```
const routersPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './routes');
fs.readdir(routersPath, (error, files) => {
    if(error) return console.log(error);
    files.forEach(file => {
        app.use(require(`${routersPath}/${file}`));
    });
});
```